# How to host Multiple cloud Anchors using ARCore in same room in Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, augmented-reality, arcore

How to host multiple cloud anchors with a memory array to store the short code of all the anchors such that many short codes are projected and in the receiver end each short code an be individually entered to retrieve the respective cloud anchor?